# How can I apply a CSS style to Html.CheckBoxFor in MVC 5

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

This seems like it should be so basic but for the life of me I can't get it working.

In my MVC 5 web app, I would like to show the user a list of layouts using checkboxes so the user can select whichever layouts are required.

I'm using an editor template, that gets called as such:

```
<table class="table">
<tr>
            <th> 
                @Html.DisplayName("Selected")
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.Layout)
            </th>
        </tr>
        @Html.EditorForModel()
</table>
```

Inside the template I use a helper for the checkbox.

```
<tr>
    <td>
         @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.IsSelected)
    </td>
    <td>    
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Layout)
    </td>
</tr>
```

This all works fine, I can capture what the user has selected in the Post

What I cannot do however is apply any CSS styles to the checkbox.

What I have read is it should be a matter of:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.IsSelected, new { @class = "css-checkbox" })
```

This however causes the checkbox to not be rendered.

I have tried a few things such as wrapping the checkbox in a

```
<div class="checkbox">
```

but even though the checkbox is rendered, I cannot select any of the items.

Now there is hopefully just something simple I am doing or not doing?

EDIT 1:

I seem to have come across the problem, but am not sure how to fix it.

If I use the following code, it works:

```
<input id="theid" name="theid" type="checkbox" class="css-checkbox" /> 
<label class="css-label" for="theid">Using input </label>
```

What I need to do is for the:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.IsSelected, new { @class = "css-checkbox" })
```

to be turned into the same as when I use input and label.

The page source looks as such:

```
<input checked="checked" class="css-checkbox" data-val="true" data-val-required="The IsSelected field is required." id="test5" name="IsSelected" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="IsSelected" type="hidden" value="false" />


<input id="theid" name="theid" type="checkbox" class="css-checkbox" /> 
<label class="css-label" for="theid">Using input </label>
```

The top comes from the helper and the bottom one is using the input tag directly.

Comment: This does sound odd. If you look at the source of the rendered markup, is there anything there at all?

Comment: `@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.IsSelected, new { @class = "css-checkbox" })` works just fine and adds `class="css-checkbox"`. What issues are you having?

Comment: Have you checked the source to see if the checkbox has in fact been rendered, but is hidden due to conflicting stylesheet rule?

Comment: @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.IsSelected, null, new { @class = "css-checkbox" }) try this

Comment: @ImranLuhur, There is no `CheckBoxFor()` extension method that accepts 3 parameters

Comment: do you have a class called css-checkbox ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16062173/4334348

Comment: @REDEVI. Yes I do, but I now believe the problem is to do with MVC finding my stylesheet. If I put a basic css style directly into the Editor Template View, such as changing the size of the checkbox, it works as expected.

Comment: you might be missing the bundling part of it ?